# What's the difference between an array and a hash whose keys are integers?

Tags: arrays, ruby, data-structures, hash

What is the difference between an array, an ordered collection of integer-indexed values, and a hash, a collection of key-value pairs, where every key is an index that starts from zero?

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]
hash = { 0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3, 3 => 4}
```

I know that it would be stupid to implement a hash like that, but what is the difference behind the hood? Are they stored in different ways in memory? What data structure makes your program faster when retrieving data from it?

Answer (score 1):

## Speed

Arrays are a better for iterating over a collection.

Hashes have almost constant lookup time `O(log n)`, while Arrays have linear time `O(n)`.
This means that you should prefer Hashes when you need to use `#include?`.

Hashes work great as dictionaries.

There is a third underutilised data structure in Ruby which behaves like a unique `Array` but uses a `Hash` underneath. This is [`Set`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html). It works great when you don't care about the order of elements, need to check if something belongs to a group or need a unique collection of elements.

## Implemetation

Yes, they are two completely different data structures.

In this particular example you could access these elements in a similar manner by calling `arr[0]` and `hash[0]`.

The line `arr[0]` is in fact sugar syntax for `arr.[](0)`. Same goes for `arr[0] = 5` which is the same as `arr.[]=(0, 5)`. Both `Array` and `Hash` have methods called `[]` and `[]=`, but under the hood completely different things would happen, because these are two separate methods with the same name.

Arrays are always indexed with integers starting with 0 and the order of items is important.

`Array` is a simple list of elements backed by a dynamic C array, while a `Hash` is an implementation of a *dictionary*/*hashmap*, a much more sophisticated data structure.

Hashes store both keys and values, and possess the ability to retrieve a value based on the received key. Every single Ruby object that implements `#eql?` and `#hash` can become a `Hash` key.
The order of elements in a `Hash` can change and is not stable.

Every `Hash` is in fact an array of slots called *buckets*. These buckets hold individual key-value pairs. To determine which key should correspond to a certain bucket, Ruby uses a hashing function, provided by the method called `#hash` on the object passed as the key. If two objects return the same value from their `#hash` method, they are considered the same key.
This goes both ways, Ruby uses `#hash` to save the key-value pair in the right *bucket*, and to find the right `value` for the passed `key`.

For example `"string".hash` will always return the same value, even though these are different objects.
This value is calculated based on the content of the `String`. This is why `String`s with the same content (even though they are different objects) are considered the same key in a `Hash`.

Sometimes two different objects (of separate classes) end up having the same `#hash`. Ruby handles these collisions by implementing individual *buckets* as linked lists of key-value pairs. So a few key-value pairs may be stored in the same bucket.

To decide which value should be returned for a given key, when there are a few key-value pairs in the same *bucket*, Ruby utilises the `eql?` method.
It compares each key stored in the *bucket* with the passed key like so `passed_key.eql?(key_in_bucket)`. When they are equal Ruby considers them a match.

Here's a great article on [Hashes](https://www.sitepoint.com/diving-into-how-hashes-work-in-ruby/).

Comment: *The order of elements in a Hash can change and is not stable* -- in Ruby hash is ordered structure. For example `{a: 1, b: 2}.first` alwats return `[:a, 1]`, and iteration through certain hash is idempotent

Comment: @mechnicov While the order of elements in `Hash` is well defined, in a certain sense it is possible for the order of keys to change. For example: `h = {a: 1, b: 2}; v = h.delete(:a); h[:a] = v; h.first` will produce `[:b, 2]`, not `[:a, 1]`. It will not change _spontaneously_, but it doesn't have a One True Ordering that an `Array` does, where `0` always comes before `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Almost every object in Ruby has a `hash` method. This method calculates some number which is unique-ish. That number is used to retrieve a key in a Hash object. If you want to get the value for `2` then the hash value for 2 is calculated (for an integer this is really fast) and looked up in the Hash object. So it looks like a hash is a way to over-complicate things - but if you want to be sure, [benchmark](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) your use-case is the way to go.